# Why is Eclipse 3.2 throwing an error on startup

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a windows 32 bit computer and just downloaded The Eclipse 3.2 SDK and can not get it to start. It immedietly throws the following error to a log file.

I have tried starting it with a java 1.5 VM and still haven't had any luck. Any Ideas? Thanks

```
!SESSION 2012-08-07 11:10:28.084 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=@build@
java.version=1.7.0_05
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY system.bundle 4 0 2012-08-07 11:10:28.519
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent.ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle system.bundle.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:1014)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:970)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.launch(StartLevelManager.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundle.resume(SystemBundle.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.launch(Framework.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.OSGi.launch(OSGi.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:173)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:977)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:952)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.checkSystemState(BaseStorage.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.getStateManager(BaseStorage.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.getPlatformAdmin(BaseAdaptor.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAdaptorHook.frameworkStart(EclipseAdaptorHook.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.frameworkStart(BaseAdaptor.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start(SystemBundleActivator.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:995)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:989)
    ... 18 more
Root exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.checkSystemState(BaseStorage.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.getStateManager(BaseStorage.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.getPlatformAdmin(BaseAdaptor.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAdaptorHook.frameworkStart(EclipseAdaptorHook.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.frameworkStart(BaseAdaptor.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start(SystemBundleActivator.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:995)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:989)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:970)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.launch(StartLevelManager.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundle.resume(SystemBundle.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.launch(Framework.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.OSGi.launch(OSGi.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:173)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:977)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:952)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-08-07 11:10:28.524
!MESSAGE Startup error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle system.bundle.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.launch(StartLevelManager.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundle.resume(SystemBundle.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.launch(Framework.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.OSGi.launch(OSGi.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:173)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:977)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:952)
!SESSION Tue Aug 07 11:10:28 EDT 2012 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.launcher 4 0 2012-08-07 11:10:28.526
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:977)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:952)
```

**UPDATE**
After reinstalling the JVM and using the -vm path parameter I still get the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
```

Comment: May I ask why you start with 3.2? 4.2 is already available and AFAIK 3.6 + 3.7 are commonly in use... 3.2 is nearly one decade old.

Comment: hope this link helps : http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t99010.html

Comment: I am developing a plugin and need to support 3.2

Comment: gaspyr: I have tried a few different flags while debugging (-clean, -vm, ect) but there are a few here that might help. I'll give them a try

Comment: An alternative is to use a more recent eclipse with a [target definition](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDE/Target_Definitions) linked to 3.2 features and plugins.

Comment: Try installing Java1.6 and edit eclipse.ini according to http://wiki.eclipse.org/%C2%A0eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Windows_Example

Comment: Are you running Eclipse from `C:/Program Files`?

Answer (score 4):

The  problem can be solved as follows.

Edit the eclipse.ini file located in your Eclipse install directory and insert -clean as the first line.

This will force Eclipse to run. You can then remove the -clean line from the .ini file

Answer (score 2):

Although this is an old thread, I'll contribute in case someone Googles this issue.  I started having this problem after Java 7 Update 11 was installed.  I uninstalled update 11 and now eclipse works just fine.  I run eclipse from \Program Files\eclipse.

Comment: Maybe you should not be using eclipse 3.2, and use 4.2 instead.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu and solved by running:

```
eclipse -clean
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the version of the JDK you are using

Don't know it it will work...

We use it for a 3rd party app which is eclipse based (very old) but it has a launhcer.ini where you specify the vm args etc.

I just added the following to be the first line.
-vm 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_22\bin\javaw.exe

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that i can think of doing is re-installing java from [here](http://java.com/en/download/index.jsp), and re-downloading and installing eclipse (the newest version) from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.2-201206081400/eclipse-SDK-4.2-win32.zip). Let me know if it works!