# Unable to launch Eclipse after set the TFS

Tags: eclipse, tfs

I'm trying to configure TFS for my project. Every was ok until i restart the eclipse. A pop up saying " An error has occurred. See the log file". Once i checked the log file its show this error. Please help.

```
!SESSION 2012-12-24 14:18:16.082 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20120608-1400
java.version=1.6.0_35
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_MY
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-12-24 14:18:16.762
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume(InternalSystemBundle.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.launch(Framework.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected to find an object at table index: 333
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.StateReader.getFromObjectTable(StateReader.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.StateReader.readGenericDescription(StateReader.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.StateReader.readBundleDescriptionLazyData(StateReader.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.StateReader.fullyLoad(StateReader.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.BundleDescriptionImpl.loadLazyData(BundleDescriptionImpl.java:662)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.BundleDescriptionImpl.getExportPackages(BundleDescriptionImpl.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.setFrameworkVersion(PackageAdminImpl.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.setResolvedBundles(PackageAdminImpl.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start(SystemBundleActivator.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 13 more
Root exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected to find an object at table index: 333
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.StateReader.getFromObjectTable(StateReader.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.StateReader.readGenericDescription(StateReader.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.StateReader.readBundleDescriptionLazyData(StateReader.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.StateReader.fullyLoad(StateReader.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.BundleDescriptionImpl.loadLazyData(BundleDescriptionImpl.java:662)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.BundleDescriptionImpl.getExportPackages(BundleDescriptionImpl.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.setFrameworkVersion(PackageAdminImpl.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.setResolvedBundles(PackageAdminImpl.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start(SystemBundleActivator.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume(InternalSystemBundle.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.launch(Framework.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-12-24 14:18:16.774
!MESSAGE Startup error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume(InternalSystemBundle.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.launch(Framework.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume(InternalSystemBundle.java:225)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected to find an object at table index: 333
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.StateReader.getFromObjectTable(StateReader.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.StateReader.readGenericDescription(StateReader.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.StateReader.readBundleDescriptionLazyData(StateReader.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.StateReader.fullyLoad(StateReader.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.BundleDescriptionImpl.loadLazyData(BundleDescriptionImpl.java:662)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.BundleDescriptionImpl.getExportPackages(BundleDescriptionImpl.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.setFrameworkVersion(PackageAdminImpl.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.setResolvedBundles(PackageAdminImpl.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start(SystemBundleActivator.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what happened, but eclipse working fine after i put `-clear` in `eclipse.ini`

Answer (score 4):

Problem only occurs when Language Pack is installed with the TFS plugin. Uninstalling the language pack solves the startup problem, so that eclipse can be started without `-clean`.

Answer (score 0):

If you install TFS language pack than it will create problem on start of eclipse firstly uninstall TFS language pack from Help menu it will clear all issue.

Other wise you have to do eclipse -clean each time you start the eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the eclipse.ini file located in your Eclipse install directory.
Insert -clean as the first line.

This will force Eclipse to run. You can then remove the -clean line from the .ini file.

[More details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849024/why-is-eclipse-3-2-throwing-an-error-on-startup)